# Can we have a Brownian motion under two different probability space?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Is it possible to construct a stochastic process $B_t$ such that $B_t$ is a Brownian under $(\Omega, F, P)$ and $B_t$ is a Brownian under $(\Omega, F, \hat{P})$? If not, how to argue that $P=\hat{P}$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion on a probability space $(\Omega_1,F_1,P_1)$ and let $(\Omega_2,F_2,P_2)$ be an arbitrary probability space. Define a new probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$ by $$\Omega := \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \qquad F := F_1 \otimes F_2 \qquad P := P_1 \otimes P_2.$$
If we set $$\tilde{B}_t(\omega_1,\omega_2) := B_t(\omega_1) \quad \text{for} \,  (\omega_1,\omega_2) \in \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2,$$ then it is not difficult to see that $(\tilde{B}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is still a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,F,P)$. Since this holds true for any probability space $(\Omega_2,F_2,P_2)$, we can easily construct a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,F,P)$ and $(\Omega,F,\hat{P})$ with $P \neq \hat{P}$.

---

Note, however, that a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ on $(\Omega,F,P)$ does determine the restricted probability measure $P|_{F_\infty}$ uniquely; here

$$F_{\infty} := \sigma(B_t; t \geq 0)$$

denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$. That is, for any probability space $(\Omega,F,\hat{P})$ such that $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,F,\hat{P})$, we have $\hat{P}(A) = P(A)$ for any $A \in F_{\infty}$.

*Proof:*  Let $P,\hat{P}$ be two probability measures on $(\Omega,F)$ such that $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,F,P)$ and $(\Omega,F,\hat{P})$. If $A$ is a set of the form $$A = \bigcap_{j=1}^n \{B_{t_j} \in G_j\} \tag{1}$$ where $t_j \geq 0$ and $G_j \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ are Borel sets, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then

$$\begin{align*} P(A) &= \mathbb{P}(B_{t_1} \in G_1,\ldots,B_{t_n} \in G_n) \\ &= \mu_{(B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_n})}(G_1 \times \ldots \times G_n) \\ &= \hat{P}(B_{t_1} \in G_1,\ldots,B_{t_n} \in G_n) \\ &= \hat{P}(A) \end{align*}$$

where $\mu_{(B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_n})}$ denotes the distribution of $(B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_n})$ (for a Brownian motion it is known that this distribution is centered Gaussian with a certain covariance matrix which can be calculated explicitly). Since sets of the form $(1)$ are a $\cap$-stable generator of $F_{\infty}$, the theorem on uniqueness of measures proves $P|_{F_{\infty}} = \hat{P}|_{F_{\infty}}$.

Comment: Under your new construction, $\Omega$ and $F$ will be different from the original construction. How about if $\Omega$ and $F$ are kept to be the same?

Comment: @will_cheuk What do you mean by "different from the original construction"? Just forget about the original probability spaces: We have a Brownian motion $(\tilde{B}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ on a probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$ and we can pick $\hat{P} \neq P$ on $(\Omega,F)$ such that $(\tilde{B}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is also a BM on $(\Omega,F,\hat{P})$.

Comment: Since this holds true for any probability space $(\Omega_2,F_2,P_2)$, do you mean that we can take $(\Omega_2,F_2,P_2)$ and $(\Omega_2,F_2,\hat{P}_2)$ (only $P_2$ and $\hat{P}_2$ are different), then consider product of $(\Omega_2,F_2,P_2)$ with $(\Omega_1,F_1,P_1)$ and product of $(\Omega_2,F_2,\hat{P}_2)$ with $(\Omega_1,F_1,P_1)$ respectively, obtaining $(\Omega,F,P)$ and $(\Omega,F,\hat{P})$ with $P$ and $\hat{P}$ not equal?

Comment: @will_cheuk Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks. But I am a little bit curious for another notes: you said that Brownian motion $(B_t)$ on $(\Omega,F,P)$ does determine $P|F_{\infty}$ uniquely, the $F$ in $(\Omega,F,P)$ should be $F_{\infty}$, am I right? How can you come across the conclusion mathematically? Any hints for it?

Comment: @will_cheuk If $(B_t)_t$ is a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,F,P)$, then $B_t$ is $F$-measurable for any $t \geq 0$ and therefore $F_{\infty} \subseteq F$. So the $F$ in $(\Omega,F,P)$ does not necessarily equal $F_{\infty}$, but it contains $F_{\infty}$. For a proof of the claim see my (edited) answer.

Comment: @will_cheuk You are welcome. If you find the answer helpful, you can upvote/accept it by clicking on the up arrow/tick next to it.